# how to wrap container to content when column is inside

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have my container only take up as much space as needed to display the content, however, since there is a column inside my container if i do not specify height, the container takes up infinite space. Does anyone know of any fix to this? My code is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../pages/selected_event.dart';

class FeaturedEventTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String eventImagePath;
  final String eventName;
  final String venueName;
  final int attendees;
  final double schoolPercentage;
  final String date;
  final String startTime;
  final String endTime;
  final String description;

  FeaturedEventTile({
    required this.eventImagePath,
    required this.eventName,
    required this.venueName,
    required this.attendees,
    required this.schoolPercentage,
    required this.date,
    required this.startTime,
    required this.endTime,
    required this.description,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double displayWidth = 0;
    double height = eventName.length > 20
        ? eventName.length > 40
            ? 305
            : 285
        : 265;
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      displayWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SelectedEvent(
                        eventImagePath: eventImagePath,
                        eventName: eventName,
                        venueName: venueName,
                        attendees: attendees,
                        schoolPercentage: schoolPercentage,
                        date: date,
                        startTime: startTime,
                        endTime: endTime,
                        description: description,
                      )));
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4, left: 4, bottom: 8),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.black38,
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    child: Image.asset(eventImagePath,
                        height: 160, width: displayWidth, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Flexible(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        eventName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: displayWidth * 0.08,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      Text(
                        '@ $venueName',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: displayWidth * 0.05,
                          color: Colors.red[200],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 4),
                      Text(
                        '$date — $startTime',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: displayWidth * 0.06,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

If I do not specify a height, the column takes up infinite space and causes an unbounded error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try set the property mainAxisSize to min

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  ...
)
```

Comment: It won't make a difference if there is a Flexible inside a Column. Flexible has no height.

Comment: But if the Column inside Flexible has MainAxisSize.min too it will not try to fill all the space. But like you have said, there's no need to have these nested Columns

Answer (score 0):

You have Flexible inside the Column. That widget wants to take all the available space, but column does not have a constraint on height.

Remove Flexible, and remove a Column inside a Column. It's unnecessary - at least in the code that you posted.